# Unable to "login" via twitter API

Tags: wordpress, twitter, gigya

I have implemented a twitter login for my site, using a plugin called "[Simple Twitter Connect](http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCEQFjAA&url=http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/simple-twitter-connect/&ei=dJKAUPeXIqnO0QX9hIHgBQ&usg=AFQjCNHNZKqD3rcYzGoRLKUCYJbj8XBXYQ)".

Now what this plugin does is create a twitter login function for my site above the the comments section which allows users to use their twitter details rather than filling out name and email boxes.

Now the problem I am having with it is when it gets to the authorize page on twitter.com, after entering the details and then going back to the site it loads solicialize.gigaya.com page.
On the contents of the page it says

> Failed connecting. Please try again later

I initially thought it must simply be something wrong with the plugin, however I have contacted the plugin author and he as said that gigya has nothing to do with his plugin nor does his plugin link to it.

I havent signed up to gigya nor implemented any of their functions on my site, so I'm not sure how this site gets into the equation.

If anyone wants to recreate the issue, the click [here](http://tinyurl.com/9sfzyyd) and login via twitter.
Can anyone suggest what the issue may be?

Comment: You are redirected to the "Callback"-URL which is defined when you create the "Consumer key"/"Consumer secret" with https://dev.twitter.com/apps - so you have to change that (or create a new key) so the callback-URL points to your Blog.

Comment: Thanks vtsm. This did the trick. You should put this as an answer rather than a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the successful OAuth-Login you are redirected to the Callback URL associated with your Consumer key. The Callback URL can be configured - here's how you do it:

- Log in to https://dev.twitter.com/apps
- Select the application which you are using in your blog
- Go to the "Settings" tab and you'll find the Callback URL under "Application Type"

Set the URL to your blog base directory (where the index.php is).